# django-braces access mxin different login_url redirect per mixin

Tags: python, django, mixins, django-class-based-views

I am using [djang-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/)

I would like to use a different login_url for each mixin called on a view.

for instance I would like all LoginRequiredMixin calls to redirect to 'accounts/login' and all MultiplePermissionsRequiredixin calls to redirect to 'accounts/permissions'.

As the 2 mixins are subclassed from AccessMixin setting the 'login_url' on a view will affect both mixins, I cannot see how I can specify a redirect for each Mixin.

I currently have views like this:

```
class View(LoginRequiredMixin, MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin, View):
    permissions = {
    "all": (<modelmethods>),
    }
    login_url = '/accounts/permissions'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cool view stuff

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cool view stuff
```

but of course this redirects both mixins to '/accounts/permissions'

I am wanting to achieve something like:

```
class View(LoginRequiredMixin, MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin, View):
    permissions = {
                   "all": (<modelmethods>),
        }
        Login_Redirect = '/accounts/login'
        MultiplePermissions_Redirect = '/accounts/permissions'

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            cool view stuff

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            cool view stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood well, but one solution I can think is:

- Set login_url to "/accounts/login"
- override check_permissions method, and set login_url to "/accounts/permissions" inside it.

This way, if login check fail it never reaches check_permissions (I suppose), and if it fallback to check_permissions you change the redirect url, so it goes to the page you want.

thought I never tried it.

Comment: I cannot override the login_url for MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin only because MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin and LoginRequiredMixin are both subclassed from AccessMixin and login_url is called from this base class, see [here](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_access.py#L20)

Comment: But it's a different object that you are overriding, you'll override only the login_url of MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin.
It'll be changed only on the check_permission stage, that happens only on MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now; your solution is about the sequence of how the methods are executed, rather than trying to have multiple attributes. It works :)